# Deixar mobile igual o desktop

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Possuo uma `section` em meu site que no desktop apresenta o comportamento esperado, uma `row` divida em 3, utilizando `col-md-4`, no desktop o comportamento está normal, no mobile tentei utilizar `col-xs-4` para ficar divido corretamente, porém o resultado não foi o esperado.

[image: Como é para ficar no desktop e mobile]

É para ter esse mesmo comportamento no mobile, porém ele esta quebrando um abaixo do outro.

[image: Como esta]

**HTML**

```
  <section class="third-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
      <h4>Entre em contato com a gente:</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 phone">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center resd">
        <p> 51 9999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 99999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 99999999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 address">
      <p>Rua XXXXX</p>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx/RS</p>
      <p>CEP 00000-000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.third-section {
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
padding-left: 35%;
padding-right: 30%;

.phone {
img {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.resd {
  margin-left: 23px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A classe com `-xs` não é mais usada no Bootstrap 4. O correto seria apenas `col-4` para breakpoints menores que 576px conforme mostra tabela na [documentação oficial do Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Neste caso, se você quer deixar 3 colunas em qualquer breakpoint, basta usar apenas `col-4`, ou seja, o `col-md-4` não é necessário já que o `col-4` é o padrão e será aplicado em qualquer resolução, já que o número de colunas não irá mudar de acordo com o breakpoint.

**Exemplo:**

Adicionei cores às colunas para visualização.

```css
.third-section {
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
padding-left: 35%;
padding-right: 30%;
}

.third-section .phone img {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.third-section .resd {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="third-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-start" style="background: red;">
      <h4>Entre em contato com a gente:</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 phone" style="background: blue;">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center resd">
        <p> 51 9999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 99999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 99999999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 address" style="background: green;">
      <p>Rua XXXXX</p>
      <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx/RS</p>
      <p>CEP 00000-000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```